# Error on Lubuntu installation

Tags: lubuntu, error-handling, debootstrap

So I was installing lubuntu normally on a 1Gb USB and after the partitions installation part the system pop up a message with a thousand error (first error) , then i found on the internet that I  have to change the file system to ext3 but now the error was the debootstrap error that the computer could not recognize the linux code name .

Comment: DEBOOTSTRAP ERROR : codename realease could not be found

Comment: Apparently the debootstrap error was caused by changing the filesystem so don't do that again. This should make it go back to showing the first error which is not very clearly explained in the question.